# BrowserFunction does not execute "JavaScript " code

Tags: javascript, java, browser

Why does `BrowserFunction` does not execute my Javascript code?

Java Code:

```
public void createBrowserFunctions() {
    new BrowserFunction(mapView_Browser, "appi") {
        public Object function(Object[] arguments) {
            syncCenter((Double) arguments[0], (Double) arguments[1]);
            syncZoom((Double) arguments[2]);
            syncRotation((Double) arguments[3]);
            return null;
        }
    };
}

private void syncCenter(final Double latitude, final Double longitude) {
    LatLng newCenter = new LatLng(latitude.doubleValue(), longitude.doubleValue());
    CENTER = newCenter;
    fireCenterChanged();
}

private void syncZoom(final Double zoom) {
    int newZoom = zoom.intValue();

    if (newZoom != this.ZOOM) {
        this.ZOOM = newZoom;
        fireZoomChanged();
    }
}

private void syncCenter(final Double latitude, final Double longitude) {
    LatLng newCenter = new LatLng(latitude.doubleValue(), longitude.doubleValue());
    CENTER = newCenter;
    fireCenterChanged();
}
```

JavaScript Code:

```
 window._handleBoundsChanged = function() {
  if( !_blockEvents ) {
    appi( 10, 15, 20, 32 );
  }
};
```

Console logs at the time of execution " _handleBoundsChanged ();" :

> ```
> osgi> !SESSION 2015-07-20 08:34:10.848 -----------------------------------------------
> eclipse.buildId=unknown
> java.version=1.8.0_45
> java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
> BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pl_PL
> Command-line arguments:  -dev 
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.rap.ui 4 0 2015-07-20 08:34:21.540
> !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
> !STACK 0
> org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to evaluate Javascript expression
>   at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.createException(Browser.java:606)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.evaluate(Browser.java:344)
>   at hc.tool.mapviewer.rap.OLMap.setZoom(OLMap.java:67)
>   at hc.tool.mapviewer.rap.View$1.widgetSelected(View.java:58)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:262)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:708)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:610)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.executeNextEvent(Display.java:1216)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runPendingMessages(Display.java:1197)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.safeReadAndDispatch(Display.java:1180)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:1172)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2733)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2694)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$5(Workbench.java:2530)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:701)
>   at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:684)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:157)
>   at hc.tool.mapviewer.rap.Application.start(Application.java:18)
>   at org.eclipse.rap.ui.internal.application.EntryPointApplicationWrapper.createUI(EntryPointApplicationWrapper.java:38)
>   at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle.createUI(RWTLifeCycle.java:171)
>   at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle$UIThreadController.run(RWTLifeCycle.java:283)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.UIThread.run(UIThread.java:104)
> ```

I am eager to method provided data from JavaScript to Java.
I count on your help , thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the evaluation is failing at `Browser:344`, after `OLMap:67` is called. You should dig into those two spots to see what is going on.

I am ready to bet that `OLMap:67` is your `function(Object [])`, and that the ultimate cause is that you are attempting to cast `Object` (possibly some kind of `JSObject`) to java `Double` without any type of conversion.